# problem of the controller (social network)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I am a beginner developer, excuse me for my English.
I have a problem with a controller that allows to follow a person on a social network.
the problem is that Postman returns me an unknown ID while it recognizes the ID in the database. here is the piece of code:

```
exports.follow = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id) || !ObjectID.isValid(req.body.idToFollow))
    return res.status(400).send("ID inconnu : " + req.params.id);
  
  try {
    // ajout du follower dans le tableau S
    req.params.id,
    { $addToSet: { following: req.body.idToFollow}}, // idToFollow = id de la personne suivie 
    { new: true, upsert: true},  // parametre obligatoire
    (err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.status(201).json(data);
      }else {
        log.error(`Problème dans else following ${error}`);
        return res.status(400).json(err);
      }
    }
    // ajout de la personne qui vous suit dans son tableau 
    await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body.idToFollow,
      { $addToSet: { followers: req.params.id}},
      { new: true, upsert: true},  // parametre obligatoire
      (err) => {
      if (err) {
        log.error(`Problème dans else followers ${error}`);
        res.status(400).json(err);
      }}
    )

  }catch (err) {
    log.error(`Problème dans catch follow ${error}`);
    return res.status(500).json ({ message: err});
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error messages you are receiving?

Comment: The code immediately inside the `try` block is non-sensical; it's a bunch of comma operators that do nothing. Is there a statement missing?

Comment: on Postman the error message is : ID unknown. but in req.params.id and req.body.idToFollow the IDs are stored there